Problem with tensorflow non linearity Apple M4 Chips
I have a problem with the result of non-linear(sigmoid) Neural Network Classification in tensorflow. I suspect is a problem with the M chip and my instalation but I tried several versions using miniforge and miniconda and conda.
Also I installed tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal in my conda environment
I check my requirements systems:

Macbook pro Apple M4 chip Sequoia 15.1.1
Python platform: macOS-15.1.1-arm64-arm-64bit
Tensor flow v: 2.16.2
Keras version: 3.7.0
Python 3.10.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Dec  5 2024, 14:20:01) [Clang 18.1.8 ]
Pandas 2.2.3
Sckikit learn 1.5.2
GPU is,available

I run the same code in my Local Jupyter and in Colab google but results are different.


My python function to visualize is this. as you can see the function is from a course. No other users has problems with the function.
def plot_decision_boundary(model, X, y):
  """
  Plots the decision boundary created by a model predicting on X.
  This function has been adapted from two phenomenal resources:
   1. CS231n - https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/
   2. Made with ML basics - https://github.com/GokuMohandas/MadeWithML/blob/main/notebooks/08_Neural_Networks.ipynb
  """
  # Define the axis boundaries of the plot and create a meshgrid
  x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 0.1, X[:, 0].max() + 0.1
  y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 0.1, X[:, 1].max() + 0.1
  xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100),
                       np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 100))

  # Create X values (we're going to predict on all of these)
  x_in = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()] # stack 2D arrays together: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

  # Make predictions using the trained model
  y_pred = model.predict(x_in)

  # Check for multi-class
  if model.output_shape[-1] > 1: # checks the final dimension of the model's output shape, if this is > (greater than) 1, it's multi-class
    print("doing multiclass classification...")
    # We have to reshape our predictions to get them ready for plotting
    y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1).reshape(xx.shape)
  else:
    print("doing binary classifcation...")
    y_pred = np.round(np.max(y_pred, axis=1)).reshape(xx.shape)

  # Plot decision boundary
  plt.contourf(xx, yy, y_pred, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu, alpha=0.7)
  plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=40, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)
  plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
  plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())

My code for neural network is this :
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model3 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

model3.compile(
    loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)

history = model3.fit(X, y, epochs=100)


Maybe try adjusting the neurons in the hidden layers (eg.  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu), you could try 4 for both relu layers.

instead I tried sigmoid for all. I guess I got the answer

By changing the hidden layers from relu to sigmoid, you ensure that each layer applies a nonlinear transformation over the entire input range. With relu, there is the possibility that the model enters a regime where a large portion of the neurons fire linearly (for example, if the values ​​are all in the positive region, relu basically behaves like the identity function). This can lead to the model, in practice, behaving almost linearly, especially if the initialization of the weights and the distribution of the data results in a saturation of the neurons in a linear region of the relu.
In contrast, sigmoid always introduces curvature (nonlinearity), compressing the output values ​​to a range between 0 and 1. This makes it difficult for the network to stagnate in linear behavior, since even with subtle changes in the weights, the sigmoid function maintains a non-linear mapping between input and output.
